# Unit testing Activity.startService() call?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, tdd, android-service

Attempting to write my first Android-by-TDD app (I've written a few small Android apps without TDD, so am familiar with the environment), but I can't seem to get my head around how to write my first test.

The scenario:

I have an activity, TasksActivity, and a service, TasksService.  I need to test that TasksActivity starts TasksService in its onStart() method.

The test I've written is this:

```
public class ServiceControlTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<TasksActivity>{
public ServiceControlTest() {
    super(TasksActivity.class);
}

public void testStartServiceOnInit () {
    final AtomicBoolean serviceStarted = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    setActivityContext(new MockContext() {
        @Override
        public ComponentName startService(Intent service) {
            Log.v("mockcontext", "Start service: " + service.toUri(0));
            if (service.getComponent().getClassName().equals (TasksService.class.getName()))
                serviceStarted.set(true);
            return service.getComponent();
        }
    });
    startActivity(new Intent(), null, null);
    assertTrue ("Service should have been started", serviceStarted.get());
}           
}
```

In my onCreate() method in TasksActivity I have:

```
    startService(new Intent(this, TasksService.class));
```

I have also tried

```
    getBaseContext().startService(new Intent(this, TasksService.class));
```

But in neither case does my MockContext's startService method get called.  Is there a way I can set up interception of this method?  I'd really rather not have to start wrapping the basic Android APIs in order to perform such basic tests...

Comment: Have you verified that your `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method is getting called through the instrumentation? I don't see anything necessarily wrong with what you're doing there.

Comment: Now, that's interesting.  It isn't.  Nor is it called if I explicitly do getInstrumentation().callActivityOnCreate(...).  But it *is* called if I comment out my mock context...  there must be some dependency on the context doing something or other in order to pass the call through.

Comment: Yup. Found this (http://www.paulbutcher.com/2011/03/mock-objects-on-android-with-borachio-part-2/), take a look. Essentially, `MockContext` is almost entirely useless :).

Comment: Yeah, I just found the same article, and switching to ContextWrapper has solved the problem.  Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to summarise the conversation with Brian Dupuis in comments, the problem was that `MockContext` doesn't provide facilities that are required by the test instrumentation in order to correctly call `onCreate()`.  Switch from `MockContext` to `ContextWrapper` solved this problem.

The working test therefore looks like this:

```java
public void testStartServiceOnInit () {
    final AtomicBoolean serviceStarted = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    setActivityContext(new ContextWrapper(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()) {
        @Override
        public ComponentName startService(Intent service) {
            Log.v("mockcontext", "Start service: " + service.toUri(0));
            if (service.getComponent().getClassName().equals ("net.meridiandigital.tasks.TasksService"))
                serviceStarted.set(true);
            return service.getComponent();
        }
    });
    startActivity(new Intent(), null, null);
    assertTrue ("Service should have been started", serviceStarted.get());
}
```

Comment: With the deprecation of ActivityTestCase and MockContext, do have an alternative to the original solution?  Thanks!