# How can I unit test that my Android Service launched a particular Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, android-testing

According to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3456034/3004881), it is possible to start an `Activity` from a `Service`.

How can I, in a `ServiceTestCase`, unit test that the correct `Intent` is passed to `startActivity()`?

`ActivityUnitTestCase` has the useful method `getStartedActivityIntent()`. And I've been able to test the converse—that an `Activity` started a `Service`—in an `ActivityUnitTestCase` by passing a `ContextWrapper` into its `setActivityContext()` method, like in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9294211/3004881).

But `ServiceTestCase` seems to have no equivalents for `getStartedActivityIntent()` or `setActivityContext()` that would help me here. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the answer is right in [the docs for `ServiceTestCase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ServiceTestCase.html).

There *is* an equivalent to `setActivityContext()`, and it's called [`setContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html#setContext(android.content.Context)). So you can call `getContext()`, wrap the context with a `ContextWrapper`, and call `setContext()`, just like with an `ActivityUnitTestCase`. For example:

```
private volatile Intent lastActivityIntent;

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    setContext(new ContextWrapper(getContext()) {
        @Override
        public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
            lastActivityIntent = intent;
        }
    });
}

protected Intent assertActivityStarted(Class<? extends Activity> cls) {
    Intent intent = lastActivityIntent;
    assertNotNull("No Activity started", intent);
    assertEquals(cls.getCanonicalName(), intent.getComponent().getClassName());
    assertTrue("Activity Intent doesn't have FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK set",
            (intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) != 0);
    return intent;
}
```

Comment: So this was just a silly mistake of mine to not notice the obviously-named `setContext()` method, but I guess I'll leave it up in case it helps someone else.